# VBA filter table and copy

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 3 column table in excel named "RFQ_selector". The 2nd column contains yes/no.

1. I need a macro that will filter the table for only rows that contain 'Yes' in the 2nd column.
2. Then the macro should copy every cell to the left of a row which contains a yes into a new location on the same sheet. Pasting them in a list starting at cell F25

I'm getting stuck, can someone help please.
Thanks

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Trader")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("C8:C22")   ' Do 30 rows
        If c = "yes" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Because StackOverflow is not a free code writing service you will need to show your code to gain any help here.

Comment: thanks for the advice, my code is now in the message

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your sub to reflect your desired changes:

> - Copy every cell to the **left** of a row which contains a yes into a new location on the **same sheet**. Pasting them in a list starting
>     at cell F25

It does not filter, there was no filtering happening in your provided code but the output only includes information for the "Yes" columns

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    'Target worksheet not needed, pasting to source worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    j = 25                                  'Start copying to F25
    For Each c In Source.Range("B2:B30")    'Change the range here to fit the range in which your data for Yes/No is stored
        If c = "Yes" Then                   'Verify capitalization here, difference between "Yes" and "yes"
           c.Offset(0, -1).Copy Source.Range("F" & j)   'Copy the cell to the left of the Yes/No column and paste on same sheet starting at row F25
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```